# Raspberry - APT : host not found - Can not update - DNS resolution issue

Tags: linux, networking, dns, apt, raspbian

Since a few weeks, I have some troubles to update apt repositories on many Raspberry / **Raspbian** devices.

I got DNS resolution issues, on any mirror I've tried in `/etc/apt/sources.list` when I use `apt-get update` command.

```
root@rpi# apt update
Err :1 http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian buster InRelease
  Erreur temporaire de résolution de « ftp.igh.cnrs.fr »
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Tous les paquets sont à jour.
W: Impossible de récupérer http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease  Erreur temporaire de résolution de « ftp.igh.cnrs.fr »
W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

It always tells me that there is a *temporary failure resolving* required host. (sorry in french in screenshot)

### Analysis & Tries

Here are settings I've tried, with always the bad result

- on different FTP & HTTP mirror URL
- From different internet connection (to check if there not a hidden proxy somewhere on my stack)
- different DNS IPs (Google, OpenDNS, internet provider) on `/etc/resolv.conf`

  ```
  # Google DNS
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  ```
- I've tried to disable wifi or ethernet, both fail
- Tried to force dns on `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

  ```
  hosts:          dns
  ```
- I've tried to disconnect VPN connexion (used for my monitoring) : still fails
- I've tried `apt clean` or `apt-get purge`
- Reboot has also been tried

### Analysis on DNS resolution & clues

- ✔ I can ping my DNS

  ```
  root@rpi:/# ping -c1 8.8.8.8
  PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
  64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=106 time=43,538 ms
  --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
  1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
  round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 43,538/43,538/43,538/0,000 ms
  ```
- I can get IP from `nslookup` command

  ```
  root@rpi:/# nslookup ftp.igh.cnrs.fr
  Server:       8.8.8.8
  Address:  8.8.8.8#53

  Non-authoritative answer:
  ftp.igh.cnrs.fr   canonical name = ftp4.igh.cnrs.fr.
  Name: ftp4.igh.cnrs.fr
  Address: 193.50.6.155
  ```
- I can `wget` the given URL :

  ```
  # wget http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease
  --2021-03-08 17:35:40--  
  http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease
  Résolution de ftp.igh.cnrs.fr (ftp.igh.cnrs.fr)… 193.50.6.155
  Connexion à ftp.igh.cnrs.fr (ftp.igh.cnrs.fr)|193.50.6.155|:80… connecté.
  requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 200 OK
  Taille : 14974 (15K) [application/octet-stream]
  Sauvegarde en : « InRelease »
  InRelease                                                           100% [===================================================================================================================================================================>]  14,62K  --.-KB/s    ds 0,03s
  2021-03-08 17:35:40 (512 KB/s) — « InRelease » sauvegardé [14974/14974]
  ```
- There is no iptables rule

  ```
  root@rpi# iptables -L
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)  
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  ```
- I've also tried `tcpdump` with  `tcpdump  -i wlan0 -v port 53` command.
  → when `wget` normally uses DNS resolution (I get some packet traces),
  → `apt` do not send any DNS resolution request...

### Workaround

If I put manual DNS resolution in my `/etc/hosts` local file : it runs good.
But on my point of view, it's not acceptable for a long term solution.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1               raspberrypi
193.50.6.155 ftp.igh.cnrs.fr
```

I fully not understand **why APT command do not use my global DNS configuration** !?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it seems to have something linked to `systemd-resolved.service`
Raspbian has replaced resolvconf default package by openresolv.

So I've tried to force reinstall of resolvconf by typing this command  and it works

```
apt purge -y openresolv resolvconf
wget http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.79_all.deb
dpkg -i resolvconf_1.79_all.deb
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
rm resolvconf_1.79_all.deb
```

Indeed, I can not use apt to force reinstall because of the original issue.
So I manually reinstall this package by downloading it from mirror site.